# Compacting code, replacing switch functions (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created script to switch content from left to right, depending on other buttons position. The code is rather big, for something so simple. How can i change/compact the code so it wouldn't take so much space and be faster?

```
switch(id) {
  case "menu-button-1":
    changActive(idElem);
    $("#offert").css("transform","translateX(200%)");
    $("#gallery").css("transform","translateX(200%)");
    $("#contact").css("transform","translateX(200%)");
  break;

  case "menu-button-2":
    changActive(idElem);
    $("#home").css("transform","translateX(-200%)");
    $("#gallery").css("transform","translateX(200%)");
    $("#contact").css("transform","translateX(200%)");
  break;

  case "menu-button-3":
    changActive(idElem);
    $("#home").css("transform","translateX(-200%)");
    $("#offert").css("transform","translateX(-200%)");
    $("#contact").css("transform","translateX(200%)");
  break;

  case "menu-button-4":
    changActive(idElem);
    $("#home").css("transform","translateX(-200%)");
    $("#offert").css("transform","translateX(-200%)");
    $("#gallery").css("transform","translateX(-200%)");
  break;
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5f3d0mmh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var index=id.split("-")[2]-1;
["home","offert","gallery","contact"]
 .forEach((el,i)=>{
  if(i<index){
  $("#"+el).css("transform","translateX(-200%)");
  }
  if(i>index){
  $("#"+el).css("transform","translateX(200%)");
  }
 });
```

Simply translate all elements before the cases index up and all after it down.

Comment: And it only goes to one direction :(

Comment: @d. Nizio edited. I think you should have a deeper loom into Arrays and their methods...

Comment: I'm pretty much begineer in programming, i just know basics. Where should i put your code?

Comment: @D. nizio replacement for your switch

Comment: It doesn't work, the whole script is in jsfiddle, as i thought that adding whole script would make post less readable. I guess there's some conflict?